# Angular country dropdown with flags

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu

I am looking for country list dropdown in angular bootstrap with flag icon and country code.

please let me know if anybody have lead.

for example: `United kingdom - us`

for reference please visit this image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEfvW.png

Looking for same drop down as image. not preferable angular-material I'm looking for bootstrap or simple design only. suggest me alternate way also

Answer (score 1):

Many Third party Library have these feature using `<ng-template>`

Check this out : https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/dropdown

For only Dropdown : https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-select/ng-select

Also you can create a custom element with Custom logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout `ng-select`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-select/ng-select

It's an exelent library for select option (or dropdown) for angular